# Only return in React after a certain condition is true?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using SlateJS and I need to delay the return of `<img src={imgSrc} />` until `imgSrc` is a defined value (it is being read as a DataURL from a blob)

Is there any way to do this?

I know this doesn't work (and that this is unwise), but theoretically could I do something *like*:

`return setTimeout(function() {return <img src={imgSrc} />, 1000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to render the image immediately after the value of the image is defined, try these:

Approach 1: use a higher order function that takes the imgSrc prop like so `<ImageComponent imgSrc={} />`

```
const ImageComponent = ({ imgSrc }) => {
    if (!imgSrc) {
        return <span></span>
    } else {
        return <img src={imgSrc} />
    }
}
```

Approach 2: render some inline code right where you were running your return statement.

```
{ this.props.imgSrc && <img src={imgSrc} />}
```

the above code is pretty cool, what it does is render the img element if the imgSrc prop is defined, other wise it does nothing. It is reactive so when the imgSrc changes, the element re renders.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Can you explain how this works a little? How can I have a React component that doesn't return a value?

When I try, I get the following: `A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

Comment: @Slapbox hey, so all react components must return something, you cannot return null or undefined. Approach 1 above either returns an empty span if there is no image or the image tag if there is an image. Approach 2 is more of a javascript expression and shorthand. if the first value evaluates to true, the second value (image in this case) is returned. If the first value is false, thats it, just another expression that evaluated to false. If this still doesnt help please share some code and maybe I can help. Good day!

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation! I think I understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the prop or value you are waiting you can simply [return null](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#preventing-component-from-rendering) on the render function when the condition is not right.
For example.

```
const ImgComponent = React.createClass({
  render() {
    if (!this.props.imgSrc) {
      return null
    }
    return (
      <img src={this.props.imgSrc} />
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: What is the consequence of returning null? Because I am doing this within a part of the SlateJS library, I don't have complete control over the process. I don't know that I can come back and render again when the `imgSrc` data is loaded.

Comment: Returning null will not render (see the link on the return null). The component will reRender every time a prop or state changes. If imgSrc is coming from an async event simply changing the state of the component that would grap it would redrawn it's children

Answer (score 0):

You do do a one liner like:

```
{ (imgSrc !== null) && <img src={imgSrc} /> }
```

This will only return an `<img>` if `imgSrc is not null, otherwise it'll behave as though the code never existed, and everything else will render.